# Conservation of Angular Momentum, why does person rotate only one way?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, angular-velocity, gyroscopes

As seen from the video that i linked, when the wheel is spinning then he doesnt rotate, but as soon as he flips the wheel he will start to rotate. Why he doesn't rotate both counter and anticlock wise?
Also why does right hand rule apply to this?

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaauRiRX4do

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 0):

The right hand rule is just a convention to decide the sign of angular momentum expressed as a vector. It applies to this video because it is the conventional rule to use.

Note that he is talking about the sign of The vertical competent of the angular momentum when he references the right hand rule: that explains the direction of $\vec L$.
It’s better just to worry about the sign of the vector than to use terms like clockwise or counterclockwise since they are not mathematical, and need to be paired with a handed rule to get a direction for an associated angular velocity.